# D3 centre point of a line (not path)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

are a few questions on here and on the D3 site about how you'd find the centre point (or any point) along a `path`, however I can't seem to find how to do it with a `line`.

I've done a [simple jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td5gzy0a/2/) here. Essentially I need to add a shape (using text in the jsfiddle to make it clearer) at a point along a line (lets say the middle for simplicity)

So I have a svg:

`var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);`

And add a line (the position is fixed and doesnt come from data)

`var line = canvas.append('line').attr('x1', 50).attr('y1', 50).attr('x2', 250).attr('y2', 150);`

The I add some text just to demo to the top and bottom of that line

```
canvas.append('text').attr('x', line.attr('x1')).attr('y', line.attr('y1')).text('top');
canvas.append('text').attr('x', line.attr('x2')).attr('y', line.attr('y2')).text('bottom');
```

`path`'s have methods to get the centre point and width/BBox etc, but `line` doesnt seem to.

Anyone have any ideas how this can be achieved?

My initial though was to just get the difference between the x1/x2 values, like this:

```
canvas.append('text')
  .attr('x', parseInt(line.attr('x2') - line.attr('x1')))
  .attr('y', parseInt(line.attr('y2') - line.attr('y1')))
  .text('just looks a bit off');
```

But as you'll see from the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td5gzy0a/2/), it's just off somehow.

Anyone want to point out my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this will work:

```
var lineData = {x1: 50, y1: 50, x2: 250, y2: 150};
var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);
var line = canvas.append('line').attr('x1', lineData.x1).attr('y1', lineData.y1).attr('x2', lineData.x2).attr('y2', lineData.y2);
console.log(line);

var x = lineData.x1 + Math.abs(lineData.x2 - lineData.x1) / 2;
var y = lineData.y1 + Math.abs(lineData.y2 - lineData.y1) / 2;
console.log([x,y]);

canvas.append('text').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).text('X');
```

Comment: this do not take about the height and width of the text!

Answer (score 1):

**Line**

Use simple mathematics, distance formula.

```js
var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

var line = canvas.append('line').attr('x1', 50).attr('y1', 50).attr('x2', 250).attr('y2', 150);
var x1 = parseInt(line.attr("x1"));
var y1 = parseInt(line.attr("y1"));
var x2 = parseInt(line.attr("x2"));
var y2 = parseInt(line.attr("y2"));

var midPoint = { x: (x1+x2)/2, y: (y1+y2)/2 };
canvas.append('text').attr('x', midPoint.x).attr('y', midPoint.y).text('X');
```

```css
line{
    stroke:#444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Path**

```js
var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

var line = canvas.append('path').attr('d', "M 50 50 L 250 150");
var path = line.node();

var midPoint = path.getPointAtLength(path.getTotalLength()/2);
canvas.append('text').attr('x', midPoint.x).attr('y', midPoint.y).text('X');
```

```css
path{
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't ask the question, comment on the question instead.

Comment: Okay Thanks Alexey :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue so thought I'd answer it incase anyone else found the question.

Used `getBBox()` of the node (using `.node()`). Used that to get the `width`, `height` and `xy`:

```
var canvas = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 500);

var line = canvas.append('line')
  .attr('x1', 50)
  .attr('y1', 150)
  .attr('x2', 50)
  .attr('y2', 250);
```

Then the middle `x` and `y` are:

```
var midX = line.node().getBBox().x + line.node().getBBox().width / 2;
var midY = line.node().getBBox().y + line.node().getBBox().height / 2;
```

Comment: If you compare your midX and midY with the values in the answer given by Philipp, you will see that the values are the same.  I suspect that getBBox is a relatively slow function, and it is more efficient to calculate the center of the line as he did.  If you do use getBBox, it would be more efficient to call it once, and cache the value in a variable.  As he noted, if you want the text to be centered properly, you also need to take into account the height of the text.